# Integrate Shopify data with R

Tags: r, shiny, shopify

I'm trying to build a Shopify app using [R Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/), but I can't find any examples of this online. Was hoping someone could post a minimal example to show how this might work.

What I've done so far:

1. I signed up as a [shopify partner](https://www.shopify.com/partners)
2. I created a test store and made 1 fake purchase
3. I created a test app

[image: test app]

4. I created a new shiny app, and installed [httr](https://github.com/hadley/httr) which looks like it will be useful for handling oauth2 authentication

.

```
library(shiny)
library(httr)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Authenticate User

})
```

Now what?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking? Can you specify? Perhaps provide some API keys to your dummy account?

Comment: I am asking to see a minimal example of a Shiny app that integrates with Shopify. For example, a shiny app that displays a store's transactions in a table.

Comment: My suggestion is you learn to use those shiny tools you list first. You need to learn R and Shiny (crawl, then walk before you run). 

Hooking up to Shopify and making a compelling App after that will then be a piece of cake. One does not learn by copying and pasting others except in the most trivial of things.

Comment: Thanks David, but I'm relatively familiar with Shiny.  I built this production app - [Trinalysis](https://gormanalysis.shinyapps.io/trinalysis/)

Comment: you can `iframe` it

Comment: Well, if you know R, and you know Shiny, working with Shopify is textbook RESTful API Internet computing. There are about a bazillion examples of that out there, so I think you're well on your way. No need to beat a dead horse.